# how can i check IP version ( 4 or 6) in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check whether IP is of version 4 or version 6.
Input is IP Address in string form.
Example :

```
IP version 4 --> 1.1.1.1
IP version 6 --> 12:1201::12:15
```

Comment: look for `.` v.s. `:`?

Answer (score 5):

You could check if the string contains a colon `:`, then it is an IPv6 address, otherwise it is an IPv4 addresss:

```
string='1.1.1.1';

if [[ $string =~ .*:.* ]]
then
  echo "IPv6"
else
  echo "IPv4"
fi
```

Comment: Although this works on its own, does not seem to work within a function.

Answer (score 2):

Native POSIX (no bashisms) solution without external calls:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" != "${1#*[0-9].[0-9]}" ]; then
  echo IPv4
elif [ "$1" != "${1#*:[0-9a-fA-F]}" ]; then
  echo IPv6
else
  echo "Unrecognized IP format '$1'"
fi
```

This uses POSIX replacements; `${1#*[0-9].[0-9]}` is the first argument, replacing the first characters up to the first number-dot-number (so it won't match the unmodified first argument), which identifies an IPv4 address and `${1#*:[0-9a-fA-F]}` is the same for a colon-hex, which identifies an IPv6 address.  As a safety, I check both and have a fallback for invalid IPs.

This is not exact, it's merely fast.  An exact match is possible in POSIX shell, but it's unwieldy.

In `perl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$_ = shift;
chomp;

if (/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$/ && $1<256 && $2<256 && $3<256 && $4<256)
  { $_ = "IPv4" }
elsif (/^(?!:\w)(?:::?[0-9a-f]{1,4}){1,8}$/i)
  { $_ = "IPv6" }
else
  { $_ = "Unrecognized IP format '$_'" }
print "$_\n";
```

in native POSIX:

```
#!/bin/sh

v4() { [ "$1" -lt 256 ] 2>/dev/null && [ $1 -ge 0 ] && [ $1 != "$2" ]; }

part="${1##*.}"
if v4 $part && v4 ${1%%.*}; then               # test 1 & 4 from 1.2.3.4
  part="${1%$part}"                            # 1.2.3.4 -> 1.2.3
  part="${part#*.}"                            # 1.2.3 -> 2.3
  if v4 "${part%.*}" && v4 "${part#*.}"; then  # tests 2 & 3
    echo IPv4
  fi
# starts with hex, has colon          AND lacks a nonhex/noncolon char
# AND lacks five consecutive hex chars and lacks 9 colons
elif [ "$1" != "${1#[0-9A-Fa-f]*:}" ] && [ "$1" = "${1#*[^0-9A-Fa-f:]}" ] \
&& [ "${1#*[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]}" \
     = "${1#*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:}" ]; then
  echo IPv6
else
  echo "Unrecognized IP format '$1'"
fi
```

Comment: Trivially fails on strings like `"123.456:something"`, which should test as "not an IP address", but with above code will test as either IPv4 or IPv6, depending on the order in which you do the tests...

Comment: So would all the other answers. Anything more would require regular expressions.  I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Even a regex would be insufficent. The right answer is to parse the string, make sure it contains the proper number of fields, separated by the proper separators, and each field value is in the valid range - e.g. 111.222.333.444 is not a valid IP address, even though most any regex that only looks at the form of the string would claim it is...

Comment: @twalberg: Regex is a lot more powerful than you think: `^(?:1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:1?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}$` will only match valid IPv4. I chose to avoid it because it's hard to read. There are regexes that will only match valid IPv6 and there are (much larger) variants that can even restrict matches to public IP space.

Answer (score 1):

To check IPV4:

```
ip='1.1.1.1'
awk -F. 'NF == 4' <<< "$ip"
1.1.1.1
```

To check IPV6:

```
ip='12:1201::12:15'
awk -F: 'NF>4' <<< "$ip"
12:1201::12:15
```

Comment: How do you return the code instead of echoing.

Comment: Use: `awk -F: 'NF>4 {exit 0}' <<< "$ip"`